# I'm having a validate issue that it keeps reapting

Tags: php

I'm trying to validate a name making sure the name wasn't use but for some kind of reason the validate error keeps repeating it self, here i want it to show when the user use the before "name already in use" but I'm getting this "name already in usename already in usename already in usename already in usename already in usename already in usename already in usename already in use". How can I stop that?

```
    $types = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `im_album` WHERE username = '".$user_data['username']."'  ");

while(($row =  mysql_fetch_assoc($result))) {
    $types[] = $row['name'];
}
if (isset($_POST['img_album'])) {
       $al_name = $_POST['name'];
       $al_description = $_POST['description'];
       $mode = $_POST['mode'];

       if(empty($al_name)){
           $errors[] = 'album name required';
           }

        if (strlen($al_name) > 55 || strlen($al_name) > 255) {
            $errors[] = 'name fields are to long ';

        }
        foreach($types  as $album){
            if ($al_name == $album) 
             $errors[] = "name already in use";

        }};
        echo output_errors($errors);
```

Comment: have you checked $types[] looks like try print_r

Comment: If you want to show the message only one time then put a `break;` after `$errors[] = "name already in use";`

Comment: @mayak swamai yea i did check my types

Comment: @tttony what do mean put a break like this type of break <br />

Comment: Take a look: http://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.break.php

Comment: how many results does $result expect to return?

Comment: @tttony it works thanks :),, and i learn something new

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach($types  as $album){
        if ($al_name == $album) {
           $errors[] = "name already in use";
           break;
        }
}
```

Try this block of code instead of the one you have there.